# Common Table Expression in a SQL WHILE loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I use a common table expression (CTE) in a while loop?  The following is give errors on the "while" statement and the reference to the "cte":

Errors: (1) Incorrect syntax near WHILE (2) Invalid object name 'cte'

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT 
     t.employee
   FROM  EmpTable as t
   WHERE (t.status = 3) 
)

WHILE ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte) <> 0)
--more stuff here
```

Comment: What do you want to do with this WHILE loop?? The CTE gives you a data set to work with - what do you want to do with it??

Comment: Hi, the code really isn't mine which I'm trying to break it down.  It (the stored proc) is littered with temp tables and while loops.  Inside the while loop there are more temp tables and selects going on based on the first result set that is being iterated.  I wanted to start breaking things down by eliminating the temp tables with CTE's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that.  The CTE's scope is only the for the next query.  It is effectively actually just a part of the query it precedes.  Just like an inline view (sub-query) is part of a larger query.

In your case you'd need to go back to good old temp tables, table variables, etc.

Comment: Closest equivalent would be a View but maybe the OP is under the misapprehension of what a CTE does anyway.